# add check constraint, get invalid data type error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Using Oracle SqlDeveloper

Table T has two columns
ID (Number)
Desc (VARCHAR2)

I try the following query to add the check:

```
ALTER TABLE T
ADD CONSTRAINT 100chk CHECK (ID BETWEEN 0 AND 100);
```

> Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
>   00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

The ID column is a number datatype - why isn't it letting me add that constraint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oracle is probably getting confused by your constraint name `100chk`. Valid names start with a letter. You can put double quotes around an invalid name and Oracle will accept it, but this is generally considered to be a bad idea.

Try naming your constraint `chk100` instead:

```
ALTER TABLE T ADD CONSTRAINT chk100 CHECK (ID BETWEEN 0 AND 100);
```

Oracle's object naming rules are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm). This link is for 10.2 but the information holds for 11.x as well.